# How to access a button's parent in Tkinter without writing class?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, event-driven

Is there any way to find a widget's parent (specifically button) without saving the parent in an object attribute?

```
but = Button(main_window, text = "close window!")
but.bind("<Button-1>", btn_handler)

def btn_handler(e):
    e.parent().destroy() # I need something like this!
    # e.parent() ==>> main_window
    # without writing class and defining self.parent ...
```

I am searching internet for several hours and I didn't find proper answer.

Comment: You can use lambda or you can use global variables. But class solution is usually the best.

Comment: @iCodez But unless I'm just ignorant, the `command` callback isn't given the event that calls it so you don't have a reference to the button that's being clicked inside the function. (Unless you explicitly pass it e.g. `but = Button(main_window, text="close window!"); but.configure(command=lambda: btn_handler(but))`

Comment: @EricLevieil would you please give link/explanation/something about "lambda"?

Comment: @MiladR `lambda` functions are anonymous functions. You'll need a tutorial, but essentially `foo = lambda num: num*2` is the same as `def foo(num): return num*2`. There's no good reason to ever NAME a lambda like I did there (by assigning it to `foo`), but they're good for one-shot functions like callbacks.

Comment: @AdamSmith - Ah, my mistake.  I've seen people bind buttons incorrectly so many times, I thought this was just another occurrence.  But in this case, it is actually necessary.  Sorry for the confusion. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `but.master` to access the parent of the `but` object.

To get the container widget of a widget that's handling a callback, you can do:

```
def callback(evt):
    handling_widget = evt.widget
    parent_of_handling_widget = handling_widget.master
    # or evt.widget.master
    parent_of_handling_widget.destroy()
```

That said, I'm not exactly sure why you're trying to avoid using a custom class. It's a natural solution to your problem.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

class MyButton(ttk.Button):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.configure(command=self.callback)

    def callback(self):
        self.master.destroy()

tk = tkinter.Tk()
b = MyButton(tk, text="close window!")
b.pack()  # or whatever geometry manager you're using

# we're done!
```

Comment: e.widget.master  is probably more what OP wants.

Comment: @EricLevieil ah, true. I wasn't really taking the intended use as context, but should have. I'll edit.

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks! I have a miscellaneous question! I know a little thing about "super" method, that you can use in order to call parent function. But I haven't seen '  **something  ' in python. Is it some kind of pointer such as C++ pointers? What is it? What's the name of its subject?

Comment: @MiladR no, they're completely unrelated. See [this canonical post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)